# How to find the first and last populated cell in a range with whitespace

Tags: excel, vba

For a macro I am using VBA to determine a daterange by finding the first and last populated row. I have found a way to find the first and last populated row, by using End.xlToRight, but that only works if it is one continuous filled row like:

```
183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 |
```

Now some rows are as follows:

```
183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | empty | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 |
```

Or

```
183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 183 | 305| 305| 305| 305
```

What would be a good way to find the coordinates of the first and last populated cells of the series with the empty cell inbetween?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share some of your code

Comment: I guess, these are **not** *rows*, but *columns*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Using the Find Method

- [`Range.Find Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

> The following is related to using the `Find` method to obtain (reference) the **NON-EMPTY range** in a **row**, a
> **column**, a **given range**, or a **worksheet**.

**The Basics**

- If the worksheet is filtered, the `Find` method will fail.
- If the worksheet has hidden rows or columns, the `Find` method will work only if the `LookIn` argument's parameter is set to `xlFormulas`.
- For these operations, the 4th and 7th-9th arguments of the `Find` method (`LookAt`, `MatchCase`, `MatchByte`, and `SearchFormat`),  are irrelevant.
- The relevant arguments are:

  - 1.) `What`, always `*`
  - 2.) `After`, default is first cell `A1` (only *First*, last cell),
  - 3.) `LookIn`, always `xlFormulas` to also work if 'cells' are hidden (not filtered!) and to include blank non-empty cells e.g. `=""`, `'`,...,
  - 5.) `SearchOrder`, (only *Range or Worksheet*),
  - 6.) `SearchDirection`, default is `xlNext` (only *Last*, `xlPrevious`).

**Interesting**

- All three screenshots are the same and show the range `A1:L12`, the used range (`UsedRange`) of the worksheet. Note how the ranges `L1:L12` and `A12:K12`, although they contain no value (are empty), are also included due to the fact that one of their cells doesn't have the default format. Therein lies the 'unreliability' to obtain the first and last non-empty cells using `UsedRange`.

**Row Perspective (Green)**

```vb
Sub FindRow()
    
    Debug.Print "Row Perspective"
    
    Const SRC_ROW As Long = 6
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Rows(SRC_ROW)
    
    ' First (Left-Most) Non-Empty Cell
    Dim fCell As Range:
    Set fCell = rg.Find("*", rg.Cells(rg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas)
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "All cells are empty in row " & SRC_ROW & "!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print "The first non-empty cell in row " & SRC_ROW _
            & " is cell """ & fCell.Address(0, 0) & """."
    End If

    ' Last (Right-Most) Non-Empty Cell
    Dim lCell As Range:
    Set lCell = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    Debug.Print "The last non-empty cell in row " & SRC_ROW _
        & " is cell """ & lCell.Address(0, 0) & """."
    
    ' Non-Empty Range
    Dim nerg As Range: Set nerg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    Debug.Print "The non-empty range in row " & SRC_ROW _
        & " is range """ & nerg.Address(0, 0) & """."

End Sub
```

[image]

Result:

```
Row Perspective
The first non-empty cell in row 6 is cell "F6".
The last non-empty cell in row 6 is cell "J6".
The non-empty range in row 6 is range "F6:J6".
```

**Column Perspective (Red)**

```vb
Sub FindColumn()
    
    Debug.Print "Column Perspective"
    
    Const SRC_COLUMN As String = "E"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Columns(SRC_COLUMN)
    
    ' First (Top-Most) Non-Empty Cell
    Dim fCell As Range:
    Set fCell = rg.Find("*", rg.Cells(rg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas)
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "All cells are empty in column " & SRC_COLUMN & "!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print "The first non-empty cell in column " & SRC_COLUMN _
            & " is cell """ & fCell.Address(0, 0) & """."
    End If

    ' Last (Bottom-Most) Non-Empty Cell
    Dim lCell As Range:
    Set lCell = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    Debug.Print "The last non-empty cell in column " & SRC_COLUMN _
        & " is cell """ & lCell.Address(0, 0) & """."
    
    ' Non-Empty Range
    Dim nerg As Range: Set nerg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    Debug.Print "The non-empty range in column " & SRC_COLUMN _
        & " is range """ & nerg.Address(0, 0) & """."

End Sub
```

[image]

Result:

```
Column Perspective
The first non-empty cell in column E is cell "E3".
The last non-empty cell in column E is cell "E10".
The non-empty range in column E is range "E3:E10".
```

**Range and Worksheet Perspective (Yellow, Blue)**

```vb
Sub FindRange()
    
    Debug.Print "Range and Worksheet Perspective"
    
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "A1:G8"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(SRC_RANGE) ' ws.UsedRange ' ws.Cells '
    ' Left-Most Non-Empty Cell
    Dim lfCell As Range:
    Set lfCell = _
        rg.Find("*", rg.Cells(rg.Cells.CountLarge), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns)
    If lfCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "All cells are empty in range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print "The left-most non-empty cell in range """ _
            & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ is cell """ & lfCell.Address(0, 0) & """."
    End If
    
    ' Top-Most Non-Empty Cell
    Dim tfCell As Range:
    Set tfCell _
        = rg.Find("*", rg.Cells(rg.Cells.CountLarge), xlFormulas, , xlByRows)
    Debug.Print "The top-most non-empty cell in range """ _
        & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ is cell """ & tfCell.Address(0, 0) & """."

    ' Right-Most Non-Empty Cell
    Dim rlCell As Range:
    Set rlCell = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    Debug.Print "The right-most non-empty cell in range """ _
        & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ is cell """ & rlCell.Address(0, 0) & """."

    ' Bottom-Most Non-Empty Cell
    Dim blCell As Range:
    Set blCell = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Debug.Print "The bottom-most non-empty cell in range """ _
        & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ is cell """ & blCell.Address(0, 0) & """."
    
    ' First Non-Empty Cell
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Cells(tfCell.Row, lfCell.Column)
    Debug.Print "The first cell of the non-empty range of range """ _
        & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ is cell """ & fCell.Address(0, 0) & """."
    
    ' Last Non-Empty Cell
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = ws.Cells(blCell.Row, rlCell.Column)
    Debug.Print "The last cell of the non-empty range of range """ _
        & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ is cell """ & lCell.Address(0, 0) & """."

    ' Non-Empty Range
    Dim nerg As Range: Set nerg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    Debug.Print "The non-empty range of range """ _
        & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ is range """ & nerg.Address(0, 0) & """."

End Sub
```

[image]

Result:

```
Range and Worksheet Perspective (Range)
The left-most non-empty cell in range "A1:G8" is cell "B4".
The top-most non-empty cell in range "A1:G8" is cell "D2".
The right-most non-empty cell in range "A1:G8" is cell "G5".
The bottom-most non-empty cell in range "A1:G8" is cell "C7".
The first cell of the non-empty range of range "A1:G8" is cell "B2".
The last cell of the non-empty range of range "A1:G8" is cell "G7".
The non-empty range of range "A1:G8" is range "B2:G7".

Range and Worksheet Perspective (Used Range)
The left-most non-empty cell in range "A1:L12" is cell "A9".
The top-most non-empty cell in range "A1:L12" is cell "I1".
The right-most non-empty cell in range "A1:L12" is cell "K5".
The bottom-most non-empty cell in range "A1:L12" is cell "D11".
The first cell of the non-empty range of range "A1:L12" is cell "A1".
The last cell of the non-empty range of range "A1:L12" is cell "K11".
The non-empty range of range "A1:L12" is range "A1:K11".

Range and Worksheet Perspective (Cells)
The left-most non-empty cell in range "1:1048576" is cell "A9".
The top-most non-empty cell in range "1:1048576" is cell "I1".
The right-most non-empty cell in range "1:1048576" is cell "K5".
The bottom-most non-empty cell in range "1:1048576" is cell "D11".
The first cell of the non-empty range of range "1:1048576" is cell "A1".
The last cell of the non-empty range of range "1:1048576" is cell "K11".
The non-empty range of range "1:1048576" is range "A1:K11".
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing beyond your  data then start at the far right of the row and go left. ie if your data was in row 1 then

```
 .cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below.
Works correctly only if data starts in column A.
for rows:

```
  last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

for columns:

```
  last_column = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

You could use also:

```
  last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Safest way is to use below formula which returns last row even if data does not start in column A.

```
  last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
```

Comment: The first two formulas are only true if the UsedRange starts with A1. If it starts with B2, both formulas are wrong. The correct formulas are: last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + 1 and last_column = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - Activesheet.UsedRange.Column + 1. BTW your last formula is brilliant.

Comment: Correct two first formulas mentioned by me works only if data starts in column A.(atleast in one column). Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you better use `CurrentRegion`

So if your data starts in cell A1, you can do: `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`

The current marked answer will give you the region of ALL data on the sheet, which is not really what was asked.