# Range Selection Method Dilemma

Tags: excel, vba

I need more experienced persons advice on some situation which I am facing. I have a test sample data in the following table.

```
hello   good    day today
hello   good    day today
hello   good    day today
hello   good    day today
hello   good    day today
hello   good    day today


hello   good    day today
                    today
                    today
```

I have used 4 ways to determine range as per following code and also the last cell by `FIND` method.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myRange1 As Range
Dim myRange2 As Range
Dim rLastCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With ws
    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
            Debug.Print ws.Name, myRange.Address
'set range with used area
    Set myRange1 = ws.UsedRange
        Debug.Print ws.Name, myRange1.Address
'set range with currentegion
    Set myRange2 = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Debug.Print ws.Name, myRange2.Address
' finding lastcell and then set range
    Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
        Debug.Print rLastCell.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Results of Debug.Print are

```
Book1         $A$1:$D$11
Book1         $A$1:$D$11
Book1         $A$1:$D$6
$D$11
```

My specific query is that by `UsedRange`, `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` and `FIND` method I get the same results. Though use of these or other approaches depend on the situation at hand but considering this particular data situation, Is over-riding preference for a particular method is warranted.

EDIT:

Based on comments of @VBasic2008  and an excellent article referred by @ QHarr , I am inclined to adopt for range determination in general situations following methodology. I would like to find Last Row and Last Column of the range utilizing the Last function suggested in [Ron de Bruin Aricle](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) . Range will be set based on Anchor Cell and Last Row and Last Column Values.Code followed by me as follows.

```
Sub Range_Detrmine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Frng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With ws
    ' Use all cells on the sheet
    Set rng = .Cells

    ' Find the last row
      LastRow = Last(1, rng)

      LastCol = Last(2, rng)

    Set Frng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    Debug.Print LastRow & ":"; LastCol
    Debug.Print ws.Name, Frng.Address
End With

End Sub



Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

I tested the above code for some example situations as per snapshots appended. I tested the correctness of range determined before deleting formatted row and after deleting the formatted row.Also in case of filter applied it is giving correct range even though filter check-marks are visible in Header Row in `Column H`
[image: Range Before][image: Range After]

```
    Debug.Print LastRow & ":"; LastCol
    Debug.Print ws.Name, Frng.Address
```

Results before and after range modification are :

```
17: 8 
Sheet1        $A$1:$H$17

14: 7 
Sheet2        $A$1:$G$14
```

I would like to know if there are some caveats to this approach.

Comment: CurrentRegion has already failed, UsedRange or SpecialCells will fail if you hide certain rows of columns or if you delete them. This leaves you with the Find method as the best (100% proof) method. But you have to use it properly: calculate the last row and the last column. `rLastCell` may be the last cell in your case, but this is not how it is done. You have actually calculated the last cell in the last row which may not be in the last column. It is assumed that the first cell is known(A1).

Comment: @VBasic2008  I did not mention `lastrow` determination as it is the most conventional approach but the point made by you regarding hidden rows or columns escaped my attention. Another point mentioned by you regarding last column, supposing `D10:D11` values are in `G10;G11` and `D10:D11` are empty, In such a case including some hidden row or column what is your advice about code syntax to be used for range determination and is fool-proof.

Comment: @VBasic2008 code syntax may not be so important as the fool-proof method or approach.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Could it be finding last cell in last row and then last cell in the last column. If so any pointer to the post covering such an approach with proper syntax.

Comment: Look at [the Find Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727142/how-to-find-the-first-and-last-populated-cell-in-a-range-with-whitespace/53733361#53733361)'s 'fractions'.

Comment: @VBasic2008  Thanks for the pointer, I shall go through it.. In simple terms combining last row with last column could serve purpose in most of the situations or there are some pitfalls there too.

Comment: @VBasic2008  your comments have clarified many doubts in my mind. You can put your formal answer , if you like for my acceptance.

Comment: If you want to determine what we think is the Used Range or Real Used Range, you use URng. If you know parts of it for sure, like in your example you know or you say A1 is the First Cell, then you can calculate just the LastUCell. But we're talking about split seconds here, so if you always use URng, there won't be any surprises. Referring to the acceptance, I might write some appropriate answer in a day or so. The topic is too vast, for me to answer right now. Study the Find method in depth, it has some tricky 'stuff', e.g. no need for MatchCase and .Cells(1,1) in you example.They are default

Comment: @VBasic2008  Thanks a lot for your advice. Look forward to your answer.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: @ QHarr  Thanks for the pointer. Seems a be a good article and would go through it especially for the caveats related to possible effects of previous formats, hidden rows and columns. After my analysis I look forward to advice on any doubts, if these  come up.

Comment: @ QHarr  I have edited my post based on the article referred by you. Many many Thanks.

Comment: @VBasic2008  I have modified my post based on inputs from you and QHarr. Thanks a lot for your kind guidance.